# New Firebase Customised Event Tracking does not capture any data

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

When google updated Firebase, it automatically took care of our old customised events and parameters. However, we now are trying to add more customised events from the new Event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics reporting.

In the new version, there is no such a thing called "register event", which I think it is totally cool, however, now, without having to register an event, even when our event name showed up in the tracking list, it did not capture any data.

Does anyone has encountered similar issues?

```
func generateInviteFrendsLink(user_id: String) {
        let key = "invite_friend"
        var parameters = [String: Any]()
        parameters["user_id_invite_friend"] = user_id
        
        Analytics.logEvent(key, parameters: parameters)
        AppEvents.logEvent(AppEvents.Name(rawValue: key), parameters: parameters)
```